# css fails once i load it into files on my hosting account

Tags: html, css, hosting

I could not find the answer to this on here, but then again maybe I worded it wrong.

I have written a simple resume website with some pretty simple design. it works great until I load it into the public files with my hosting. just just a couple small things no longer follows all of the css i had written.

the site is whatshupp.com if you want to see what I mean. the maintenance page doesn't completely follow the css nor do the h1's on the homepage and somehow it worked fine before I load it up.

its not cashed data

is Hostinger the issue? Please help

Comment: try using the full link to the css: http://whatshupp.com/whatshupp.css